# Chrome ignores css rule with ::-ms-check

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-check {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

This rule will be completely ignored by Chrome. When I remove `input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-check` — it works okay. Is there any way workaround except creating two separate rules for Chrome and IE?

Comment: An invalid selector part invalidates the complete rule. If Chrome considers `::-ms-check` invalid, then you have little other choice than to make this two separate rules. This is similar to the situation with `@keyframes` - here you can’t get away with “grouping” all the vendor prefixes into one either.

Answer (score 0):

don't use ::-ms-check instead use the :checked , which is supported by all browsers

check that you are using this syntax :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

i run this example in chrome and IE11 and they both worked correctly.

Comment: ::-ms-check is the only way to customize check box tick in IE.

Comment: in that case i think you need to duplicate it